# is there an option to create strategies with indicators in tradingview without writing code?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I didn't realize that you have to write all the code yourself in order to make strategies with indicators in tradingview. Isn't there a way to do it without writing all the code?

e.g. like a pre-programmed menu in the software where you can choose indicators you want to have in your strategy. then add settings like alerts, entry, exit, stop loss etc from a list in the software?

All I find is the indicator menu in tradingview but there is no way to connect them to a "strategy" without writing pine.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `pinescript` is a text-based language. Tradingview does not support any other programming languages -something like model based/graphical.

But they offer a [reliable programmer](https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000601677-where-can-i-find-a-reliable-pine-programmer-to-hire/) list if you want to get professional help.

Otherwise, [reference manual](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/) and [user manual](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/index.html) are good places to start learning the language.